# what is alternative of custom type in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, database-design

In sql server it is very easy to pass data as a custom type to sql server and then iterate it and perform operations. but in mysql if i have 1 order that has many inventory with it like my order scheme is

```
order (id,customer_name,phone,address,total,created_date)
orderdetails(id,order_id,inventory_id,quantity,amount,created_date)
```

so when i will make stored procedure what should i do i can have many inventories among with 1 order.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no other way than to make a series of calls adding one order_detail after the other, possibly inside a transaction.

In java, using jdbc, it's possible to do this inside a batched statement saving some round trips to the database.

Comment: is there any way in php?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's possible in php.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not mention PHP or any other language.

So in pure MySQL (meaning on its own like for Event processing or the ability to be called by any language) ... you call a Stored Procedure with a parameter representing the `order.id`.

Now in the Stored Proc you either find a smart fast way to deal with those `orderdetails` under that `order.id` in SQL's sets and relations. This should be the Goal.

Or (read: you are either new to SQL or it is just too tricky) you swing for the slow route and create a MySQL `CURSOR` to iterate (fetch) the next row and inside a processing loop you deal with those `orderdetails.`

A MySQL Cursor gets its life started with a simple `SELECT` statement.

If I ever see a `CURSOR` in a Stored Procedure it always raises a red flag. But sometimes you just seem to have to do it that way. Just because a `CURSOR` can get the job done doesn't mean you should be proud of yourself. It may very well run 50 times slower than with sets and relations.

So there is no need for custom types (the title of your question).

Comment: i only want to know how to pass list of orderdetails to stored procedure in my sql? i know how to deal with cursor or other methods

Comment: Simple. I said it in the second paragraph above: *you call a Stored Procedure with a parameter representing the order.id*

Comment: I think OP want't so _insert_ one order with several order_details in one call.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand "iterate it and perform operations" ... we have no idea. But the stored proc would have the `order.id` and he is off to the races. He just said he knows how to do cursors. I have no idea if he knows how to do sets and tricky stuff.

Comment: I interpret that as "iterate and perform operations" on data sent to the procedure, not data that is already in the database.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand the op can let us know